# jQuery get variable value from another html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, get

I have got an html page with this content, called "page1.html":

```
<div>
    <div id="content">
        content
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var x=5;
        var y=2;
    </script>
    <div id="other">Some other content</div>
</div>
```

In another html page, I'd like to get the value of the variable "x" (5).
This is the main page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="new_content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is the app.js script:

```
$(function(){
    $.get('page1.html', function(result){
        var obj = $(result).find('script');
        $(this).append($('#new_content').text(obj.html()));
    });
});
```

And the result is "var x=5; var y=2;". Is there a way to get only the value 5 from the var x?

Thanks for the help.

EDIT: I forgot to write that it's only an example, the code into the script in page1.html is more complex than the one shown. The object "obj" in app.js is an [object htmlscriptelement] so I'd like to know if a method/att exists that I can use to directly access the var x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a bit of a weird thing to try and do.

I'll do my best to answer but it would be good to get a bit more context around why you want to do this as it might be that there's a better, cleaner way to do it.

My recommendation with the information that you've given would be to assign the values to a DOM object, jQuery is built to traverse the DOM and manipulate it, it's really not a good idea to try and parse raw javascript to extract variable values.

So, page 1 would look like this:

```
<div>
    <div id="content">
        content
    </div>
    <div class="myData" data-x="5" data-y="2" />
    <div id="other">Some other content</div>
</div>
```

Then my jQuery would look something like this:

```
$(function(){
    $.get('page1.html', function(result){
        var obj = $(result).find('script');
        var page1X = $(result).find('div.myData').data('x');
        var page1Y = $(result).find('div.myData').data('y');
    });
});
```

This is just pseudo code, but hopefully you get the idea.

Reference links:

- http://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: Hi, I need to load different pages in my index page (sequentially), but I'd like to allow the user to go to the next page only if a specified flag in the currently loaded content is set.

Comment: And do as jolyonruss propose and add a data-value a json object (constructed with all you need) ?

Answer (score 5):

Or you can simply use [localStorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) in this way:

**page1.html**:

```
localStorage.setItem("x", "value"); //setter
```

**page2.html**:

```
var x = localStorage.getItem("x"); //getter
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try to comment the vat y=... line before pasting the code like:

```
$(function(){
    $.get('page1.html', function(result){
        var obj = $(result).find('script');
        $(this).append($('#new_content').text(obj.html().replace('var y','//var y')));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To get value from another html page
for example page1

```
<input type="text" id="pageoneinputid" value="pageone">
```

on page two in the script tag

```
var a=$("#pageoneinputid").val()
document.getElementById("pagetwoinputid").innerHtml=a;
```