# Sharing <div> from another live Page

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Any suggestions on how to get or borrow the div from another page. My pages consist of two `csr view(customer service representative terminal)` and the `customers terminal view`

Right now I'm doing a queuing system what I want to do is share some part of div of the `csr` view to the `terminal` view

`terminal` view is only a view of data like que code for them to know whos next to be call by our `csr` and etc and I want to include there the timer for every que that the `csr` made, a timer must set and I want to display this timer on the `terminal` view itself as well for the customer to know how long it is already for that cue, obviously timer must only initialized on the `csr` view page only and cant be on the `terminal` view

and `terminal` view is only viewing on a wide screen tv/monitor so user/customer cant navigate it

my code for the timer is here

```
    <div class="stopwatch">
        <div class="controls">
            <button class="start">Start</button>
            <button class="stop">Stop</button>
            <button class="reset">Reset</button>
        </div>
        <div class="display">
            <span class="minutes">00</span>:<span class="seconds">00</span>:<span class="centiseconds">00</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="stopwatch/stopwatch.js"></script>
```

I need to borrow or get/share the `<div> <div class="display">` and display it on the `terminal` view and if the que is finish timer will stop and on the next and same process must be initialized.

I look for some similar question but it is not the exact what i need
[jQuery get variable value from another html page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23562147/jquery-get-variable-value-from-another-html-page)

my structured pages is like this

```
RQS
 |_csrpage(index.php where stopwatch is included)
 |_terminalview(index.php inside here must display)

they are both from separate folder
```

Comment: simply create one separate view which you have include in both view pages

Comment: are both pages running in different tabs at the same time? You might look at `window.postMessage` to send data between the windows/tabs

Comment: yes they are both running on different tabs the terminal view is just another tab which can be viewed on different monitor(extended)

Comment: @KrishnaJonnalagadda if rquire or include is your suggestion i think its just only create a seperate timer,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the window with the `DIV` that you wish to `get or borrow` can be opened using a standard hyperlink or similar on the main window then it is fairly trivial to share data between pages using [`postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) after capturing a reference to the [opening page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/opener)

As example here are two basic html pages.

**index.html**
*the main page that is to display the "borrowed" data*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title></title>
        <script>
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
                const view=document.getElementById('view');

                window.addEventListener('message', function(e){
                    view.innerHTML=e.data
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href='source.html' target='_blank'>Open Source page with clock/timer</a>
        <div id='view'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**source.html**
*the page with the timer/ clock ( data to be "borrowed" )*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title></title>
        <style>#clock{border:1px solid black;padding:1rem;text-align:center;width:50%;float:none;margin:auto}</style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='clock'></div>
        <script>
            (function(){
                const target=window.opener;
                (function(){
                    document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML=new Date().toLocaleTimeString('en-GB');
                    target.postMessage( document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML, '*' )
                    setTimeout( arguments.callee, 1000 );
                })();
            })();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

In the above `source.html` page there is a simple clock running which acts as the data to be shared with the original page. In your code this would be your timer

Comment: glad I was able to provide some assistance and get you on the way to solving your problem. good luck

Comment: One thing to note ( you will find it mentioned in the Mozilla documentation ) is to be aware of the message `origin` - you should add a check in the message listener to check the origin of the message and prevent unauthorised messages being processed by your code. Within a corporate environment this ought not be an issue however